# AWS API Gateway - Remove Stage Name From URI

Tags: aws-api-gateway

The stage name is added to the url when I deploy the API. Let's say the stage name is "test", then the generated URL for the resource includes the stage name. Something like:
https://abcabc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/my/path

I would like to remove the stage name in the URL. How can I do it?

Comment: I ended up setting up a Cloudfront distribution to use a custom domain name and then used a Cloudfront function to remove the stage name that was appended to my custom domain name for my Zappa deployed Flask app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69504366/use-cloudfront-to-remove-stage-from-custom-domain-url/69545281#69545281

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do this with API Gateway [Custom Domains](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html). This allows you to optionally omit the stage name in the custom domain name mapping by setting path to `*`.

Comment: So, in the example above, "mydomain.com/my/path" point to my "test" stage? it wouldn't show "mydomain.com/test/my/path" ?

Comment: That's correct - you can omit the stage name in the custom domain mapping

Comment: @RyanG in which step we can omit the stage name? I could only see `path (optional)` in the `Configure API mappings` panel. If I put in `somepath` for the Path, the api becomes `https://example.com/somepath/dev0/yyyy` but the stage name `dev0` is still there

Comment: @RyanG my bad, just tried, setting `path (optional)` works

Comment: @RyanG where exactly you seen an option for omitting the stage name in the custom domain settings?

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me as my APIG is private and can't use a custom domain name

Comment: To be clear in the Custom Domain, you need to add a Path mapping where you just put * as only mapping

Comment: "You must have a registered internet domain name in order to set up custom domain names for your APIs"

Comment: Michael, could you add @Kyriba 's answer as an edit for 2024? This answer is not working for me and the other one is doing the job.

Answer (score 15):

I'm using public HTTP API and no CloudFront. The Config Mapping solution did not work for me. The path was still prepended with the stage name, whether I used `*` or just an empty path as a mapping Path.

I have a single catch-all route, `ANY /{proxy+}` with a single Lambda integration.
To make it work I configured Integration parameter mapping to overwrite the path with `$request.path` - It is ["The request path, without the stage name."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-parameter-mapping.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this! This is the best answer to this question.

Answer (score 12):

I was unable to use the custom domains approach in the accepted answer because my api gateway is already in use with the stage in the url. I needed to remove the stage for a particular route. For this example, this route: https://example.com/apple-app-site-association needs to hit api gateway route: https://example.com/v1/apple-app-site-association.

Using cloudfront,

in the **Origins** tab, create a new origin to point to the api gateway including the stage:

Origin Domain Name: `example.com`

Origin Path: `/v1`

Origin ID: (give this a unique name and note this for next step)

(Leave remaining settings as default or change as you require, I set Origin Protocol Policy: `HTTPS Only`)

in the **Behaviors** tab, create a new behavior:

Path Pattern: `/apple-app-site-association`

Origin: (the Origin ID you set above)

(Leave remaining settings as default or change as you require)