# API Gateway - How Deploy API works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

After **creating** API Gateway with two API names and integrating with lambda function,

AWS documentation recommends to **deploy** this API, as shown below:

### [image]

1) What does deploy API mean? How creating API gateway different from deploying API?

2) Does deploy API option internally create Cloud formation template? that creates a stack and deploy

Answer (score 2):

1) What does deploy API mean? How creating an API gateway different from deploying API?

Let' say you have created your API but how about making it public so that it can be used.

That's where deploy comes. Once you are done with writing your API, deploy it to make it callable by your users. When you deploy, then you get the link from API Gateway which can be accessed by everyone.

It is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api.html)

2) Does deploy API option internally create Cloud formation template? that creates a stack and deploy

No, Like you said you have integrated a lambda function with your API then API Gateway will simply redirect all the calls to your lambda function which is serverless.

Comment: Is deploying nothing but creating AWS resources? API gateway is another resource. Here is one example: https://bl.ocks.org/magnetikonline/c314952045eee8e8375b82bc7ec68e88

Comment: Deploying simply means making your API callable. If you create an API and you want me to call it that will only be possible if you deploy it first. Cloudformation template will help you create your API's, create your Lambda function, help you do the integration of both. Here if you are creating API using console then deploy will make it usable by others.

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485799/inbuilt-authentication-mechanism-api-gateway

Answer (score 2):

An API Gateway is a Proxy that manages the endpoints ,It acts as the single entryway into a system allowing multiple APIs or microservices to act cohesively and provide a uniform experience to the user.

The most important role the API gateway plays is ensuring reliable processing of every API call. In addition, the API gateway provides the ability to design API specs, help provide enterprise-grade security, and manage APIs centrally.

[image]

> An API Gateway is a server that is the single entry point into the
>   system. It is similar to the Facade pattern from object‑oriented
>   design. The API Gateway encapsulates the internal system architecture
>   and provides an API that is tailored to each client. It might have
>   other responsibilities such as authentication, monitoring, load
>   balancing, caching, request shaping and static response handling.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/design/gateway
- https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html

### Deploying a REST API in Amazon API Gateway:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-tutorials.html
- https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws-api-gateway/custom-authorizers/part-1
- https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws-api-gateway/custom-authorizers/part-2
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api.html

Answer (score 1):

#### meaning of `deploy` & `stage` in Api Gateway

- > To understand what truly “Deployment” in API Gateway is,

  **see https://medium.com/@lancers/deployment-in-amazon-api-gateway-128c522c762e** explains it well.
- basically, you must **deploy** the Api so you can **use** it.

  Also, the design of it is poor (/ confusing) 
  -- you must **redeploy** it manually,, everytime if you **change** the Api. 
  Otherwise, the Api will still be using the "**old** deployment snapshot". 
  and you may not notice it. \

#### meaning of `stage`

- > You will have different URL's for each stage. like `https://api-gateway-domain/dev/...` , `https://api-gateway-domain/qa/..`,`https://api-gateway-domain/prod/..`. Basically the URL would be `https://api-gateway-domain/<stage_name>/..`.

  see [What is a "stage" in the context of Amazon API Gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848586/what-is-a-stage-in-the-context-of-amazon-api-gateway)
- basically, it just a path prefix to your url

#### how to delete my deployment snapshot

- idk, seems not deletable