# Does AWS API Gateway require a stage to be accessed by Postman?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, postman, gateway, stage

Recently I had a contracted company do some work and part of that was to create an API Gateway. When I create one I add a stage with usage plan so I can add an API key. They did not. So now when I attempt to hit it with Postman it is always reporting "forbidden".

Is a stage required for the API Gateway to be usable by Postman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in the docs at AWS here: [Publishing REST APIs for customers to invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/rest-api-publish.html)

It states:

> Simply creating and developing an API Gateway API doesn't automatically make it callable by your users. To make it callable, you must deploy your API to a stage.

So **YES**, a stage is required for the API Gateway to be usable by Postman.